# DataBinding Between 2 WPF Windows with 2 TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following problem,I don't know why my DataBinding doesn't work(I did one already in my program on the same way and it works). Maybe it doesnt work coz I pass the MainWindow and go to Window2,but my reference set up on Window2 for MainWindow only.Still dunno how to solve it. My code (Sorry had to cut it,i hope i didnt forget anything,since the 2 windows over 600 or 700 rows of code)

```
private void btLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Window2 = new Window2();
    Login USERTB= new Login(); //reference to reach the Login table and check if we can read the logged user from it
    Window2.Show();
    USERTB.Username = tbLoginUser.Text;  //checking if it knows the username- working yet
    this.Hide();
}
```

After this,the problem starts,the value of my textbox from mainwindow didn't pass to the second one even if I try to get it with the USER reference. Here is the Window2.xaml & Window2.cs:

Window2.cs:

```
string action;
public string Action
{
    get { return this.action; }
    set { this.action= value; OnPropertyChanged("Action"); }
}



private void SmthHappens(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var felh = new MainWindow(); 
    Action= felh.USER; //in here didn't pass the MW's tb value ,so here is the problem
    tbShow.Text = Action;
}
```

I try to pass MW's tb value to W2 tbShow. I guess my code is wrong at SmthHappens,coz I've already passed MW and it lost the value of tbLoginUser. But I don't know how to solve it. Please help!

SOLVED! Thanks for the answers,I solved it on the same way as I try to do it. Maybe I will check MVVM a bit later,but now I don't have much left from my program,so I end it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases the MVVM pattern commonly used in WPF comes in handy. You should create a model class, containing the properties you want to share, and pass that through a View Model to the two forms.

More on the MVVM design pattern used in WPF, read [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the `MainWindow` so the `var felh` does not contain any data you have put in the first instance of the `MainWindow` before. You should use a Model (class for the data you need) a ViewModel (here you create the instance of the Model and fill in the data) and use this ViewModel for your two Windows (=> Views). That would be the use of the MVVM pattern (in a nutshell). 
I suggest you this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

If you never touched the MVVM before it won't be easy in the first steps but after a example / test programs tests you will get it and it will make things easier then ever!

EDIT: if you dont want to learn it and want to get a dirty solution you could try out a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern for the `MainWindow`

Comment: Thx for the answers! Solved it without MVVM or singleton. But I will check it :)